# Ansible: convert a list with unicode to a list of strings (and compare them)

Tags: list, ansible, diff, python-unicode, ansible-awx

I created a list with all the **ansible group hosts**.
But when I print the list it contains unicode characters. **u'text'** instead of **"text"**
Is there any efficient way to remove/convert this.
I looked at other examples online but didn't succeed.

Current (wrong) output with unicode characters:

```
ok: [server.name] => {
"msg": " [u'all', u'coaster', u'aes', u'curo, u'dert', u'tomcatdeploy', u'implus-app', u'domain-top', u'tp-general', u'cdaes01', u'dicco-acc' .....
```

This should have an **identical format like the following list**. Because I want to compare them with diff.
The values in the list itself are different, but should be formatted like:

```
ok: [server.name] => {
"msg": [
    "tools", 
    "tools-api", 
    "adr-app", 
    "adr-app-e2j", 
    "aec", 
    "aec-copy", 
    "aes", 
    "aes1", 
    "aes2", 
    "aes3", 
    "ais", 
    "apiman", 
    "apiman-gateway-poc", 
    "apiman-manager", 
    "apiman-manager-poc", 
    "apollo-beheer-aangiftes", ...
```

Currently I'm using following code to fetch the list:

```
- name: register groups
  set_fact:
    inventory_groups: []  # empty list
    inventory_group_keys: "{{ groups.keys() |to_yaml}}" #|list

- name: clean white spaces from list
  set_fact:
    inventory_groups: "{{ inventory_groups}} + ['{{item.strip()}}']"
  with_items: "{{inventory_group_keys[1:-2].split(',')}}"

- name: print inventory_groups from local host for debugging
  debug:
    msg: " {{ inventory_groups }}"
```

The second list is fetched with an AWX api. 
Also note that for some reason there seems to be a **" before the [ bracket** .
Like highlighted below:

```
"msg": " [u'all',....
```

Which isn't in the first list. Any idea why this is. I assume this will give problems when comparing them later on.
The way that I create the lists is identical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This ended up solving most of my issue.

```
- name: print list
  debug:
    msg: "{{ groups | list }}"
```

Which gives following list:

```
ok: [server.name] => {
    "msg": [
        "all", 
        "coster", 
        "ius1", 
        "curo", 
        "derti", 
        "tomcatdeploy", 
        "implus-app", 
        "domain", 
        "tpgeneral", 
        "cdaes", 
        "diccop-acc", 
        "cdaes", 
         ....
```