# how to remove 'u' from list output in ansible

Tags: ansible, cisco

I'm trying to do a simple list to show all ports associated with a particular vlan and have this output to a csv.

Code works but can't figure out how can I get around removing the 'u' and the [] associated with the line 'InterfaceID' in the output. I know the array need to be converted to a string just wondering how I can do this without modifying the code too much.

Thank you in advance for any tips.

Code:

```
   - name: parse output
     set_fact:
      vlan_output: "{{vlan_info.stdout[0] | parse_cli_textfsm(parse_template)}}"

   - name: write lines to file
     copy:
      content: "{{ ['InterfaceID','VlanID','NAME'] | zip([item.INTERFACES,item.VLAN_ID,item.NAME]) | map('join', ', ')  | join('\n') }}"
      dest: "output.csv"
     with_items: "{{vlan_output}}"

   - debug:
      var: vlan_output
```

**Debug of vlan_output:**

```
"vlan_output": [
    {
        "INTERFACES": [
            "Gi1/0/2",
            "Gi1/0/5",
            "Gi1/0/7"
        ],
        "NAME": "test",
        "STATUS": "active",
        "VLAN_ID": "10"
    }
]
```

```
Excel Output:
InterfaceID, [u'Gi1/0/2', u'Gi1/0/5', u'Gi1/0/7']
VlanID, 10
NAME, test
```

Comment: Does [convert a list with unicode to a list of strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58169705/) answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

While you cannot directly do that, once you upgrade version of python used by ansible to 3.x you get rid of these.  Only Python 2.x does print unicode strings with `u` prefix. On 3 all are unicode anyway and the prefix is not printed anymore.

Keep in mind that the `u` is part of printing the data, is not part of the data itself.

If you try to parse as string an array that was converted to a string you are already doing something wrong.

Comment: yep i knew the u was not part of the data but thanks for letting me know about the version upgrade. will try this!

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a list of Interfaces, you can use the `join` filter to "join" the list items into a string. From the question its not clear if you'd like to join them with space or comma, but a small change, such as - `item.INTERFACES|join(', ')` will give (comma separated) - `Gi1/0/2, Gi1/0/5, Gi1/0/7`.

Example:

```yaml
    - name: write lines to file
      copy:
        dest: output.csv
        content: "{{ ['InterfaceID','VlanID','NAME'] | zip([item.INTERFACES|join(', '),item.VLAN_ID,item.NAME]) | map('join', ', ')  | join('\n') }}"
      with_items: "{{ vlan_output }}"
```

Produces:

```
InterfaceID, Gi1/0/2, Gi1/0/5, Gi1/0/7
VlanID, 10
NAME, test
```